# Python - Sort 4 lists according to the sorting of the first list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have 4 lists and want to sort the first list from smallest to largest and then apply the same changes to the second, third and fourth list.

For example:

`nodeA = ['1', '4', '3', '5' , '2']
 nodeB = ['0', '5', '0', '6', '3']
 identity = ['R', 'G', 'C', 'L', 'L']
 value = ['100', '125', '300', '400', '275']`

Would go to:

`nodeA = ['1', '2', '3', '4' , '5']
nodeB = ['0', '3', '0', '5', '6']
identity = ['R', 'L', 'C', 'G', 'L']
value = ['100', '275', '300', '125', '400']`

(I think I did that right)

Im not sure how to do this, any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you gather the data into a single object first? Or must you use the original lists (exclusively)?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a version of `argsort()` for Python `list`s:

```
def argsort(seq):
    ix = list(range(len(seq)))
    ix.sort(key=seq.__getitem__)
    return ix
```

which you can use to reorder all lists:

```
nodeA = ['1', '4', '3', '5' , '2']
nodeB = ['0', '5', '0', '6', '3']
identity = ['R', 'G', 'C', 'L', 'L']
value = ['100', '125', '300', '400', '275']

ix = argsort(nodeA)
nodeA = [nodeA[i] for i in ix]
nodeB = [nodeB[i] for i in ix]
identity = [identity[i] for i in ix]
value = [value[i] for i in ix]

print(nodeA)
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
print(nodeB)
# ['0', '3', '0', '5', '6']
print(identity)
# ['R', 'L', 'C', 'G', 'L']
print(value)
# ['100', '275', '300', '125', '400']
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

We can use a combination of `zip` and `numpy` to make this happen quickly.

```
import numpy as np

a, b, c, d = np.transpose(sorted(zip(nodeA, nodeB, identity, value)))

for arr in (a, b, c, d):
    print(arr, '\n')

['1' '2' '3' '4' '5'] 

['0' '3' '0' '5' '6'] 

['R' 'L' 'C' 'G' 'L'] 

['100' '275' '300' '125' '400']
```

We can also do it without `numpy` and use `zip` twice.

```
a, b, c, d = zip(*sorted(zip(nodeA, nodeB, identity, value)))

for arr in (a, b, c, d):
    print(list(arr), '\n')

['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] 

['0', '3', '0', '5', '6'] 

['R', 'L', 'C', 'G', 'L'] 

['100', '275', '300', '125', '400']
```

Caveat: This won't work as expected if all the lists aren't the same size.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at the other answers if you must continue using lists.

However, if each index in all of the lists is tied to a certain object (I'm imagining some measurement device with two nodes, an identity, and a measured value), then a more complex data structure might be a better option for you.

Say you created a class `Device` like this

```
class Device:

    def __init__(self, nodeA, nodeB, identity, value):
        self.nodeA = nodeA
        self.nodeB = nodeB
        self.identity = identity
        self.value = value
```

and then created 5 instances of that class.

```
devices = [Device(1, 0, 'R', 100),
           Device(4, 5, 'G', 125),
           Device(3, 0, 'C', 300),
           Device(5, 6, 'L', 400),
           Device(2, 3, 'L', 275)]
```

You could then easily sort this list using the built-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function (with the optional `key` argument) and the [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) function from the builtin `operator` module. This will sort the list of objects by the function you gave as the key, specifically a function that gets the desired attribute you want to sort by.

```
import operator
sorted_devices = sorted(devices, key=operator.attrgetter('nodeA'))
```

Here the devices are sorted by the `nodeA` attribute, but now you could also easily sort them by any of the other attributes as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have strict performance/memory requirements, and lists are little and of a fixed number, you could try this script, maybe it's the easier way to implement.

```
nodeA = ['1', '4', '3', '5' , '2']
nodeB = ['0', '5', '0', '6', '3']
identity = ['R', 'G', 'C', 'L', 'L']
value = ['100', '125', '300', '400', '275']

s_A = sorted(nodeA)
s_B = []
s_i = []
s_v = []

for i in range(len(nodeA)):
    index = nodeA.index(s_A[i])
    s_B.append(nodeB[index])
    s_i.append(identity[index])
    s_v.append(value[index])

print(s_A)
print(s_B)
print(s_i)
print(s_v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of tuples and sort it, and use the information from it to sort the other lists...

```
>>> nodeA = ['1', '4', '3', '5' , '2']
>>> tracker = [(item, i) for i, item in enumerate(nodeA)]
>>> tracker.sort()
>>> tracker
[('1', 0), ('2', 4), ('3', 2), ('4', 1), ('5', 3)]
```

Now we have a list of tuples sorted on the first item, with their original position as the second item. We can use that position value as an index into the other lists.

```
>>> nodeB = ['0', '5', '0', '6', '3']
>>> identity = ['R', 'G', 'C', 'L', 'L']
>>> value = ['100', '125', '300', '400', '275']
>>> 
>>> for li in (nodeA, nodeB, identity, value):
...     li = [li[i] for item, i in tracker]
...     print(li)
...     
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['0', '3', '0', '5', '6']
['R', 'L', 'C', 'G', 'L']
['100', '275', '300', '125', '400']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dict mappings

```
d = {}
for a_value, b_value, i_value, value in zip(nodeA, nodeB, identity, value):
    d[a_value]=[b_value,i_value,value]
nodeA = sorted(nodeA)
```

And use lookup for the values again using dict you just created

```
nodeB=[d.get(i)[0] for i in nodeA] #['0', '3', '0', '5', '6']
identity=[d.get(i)[1] for i in nodeA] #['R', 'L', 'C', 'G', 'L']
value=[d.get(i)[2] for i in nodeA] #['100', '275', '300', '125', '400']
```